# How to show different modal dialogs from inherited classes in Angular Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a question related to inheritance and displaying modal dialogs.  I am using Angular Dart and am not sure how to accomplish what I want.  I have been unsuccessful in finding any useful examples.

I currently have an abstract base Task class and a TaskA class that extends the Task class.  Both are NgTwoWay components.  The main html is just a simple form with a button on it.  When the button is clicked, I want a modal dialog to display.  This modal will either be one from TaskA or TaskB depending on which type of task was created.  The problem occurs when I try to show the modal from the extended class.  I don't think the TaskAComponent is getting created so the html is not accessible or does not exist yet.  I have also tried making the TaskComponent abstract and TaskAComponent extending from it but then none of the task html shows up.

Here is the code I currently have.

task_component.dart

```
abstract class Task {
  Scope _scope;

  Task([this._scope]) {
  }

  void displayProperties();
}

@Component(
    visibility: Directive.CHILDREN_VISIBILITY,
    selector: 'task',
    templateUrl: '../lib/components/task_component.html',
    publishAs: 'taskCmp',
    useShadowDom: false)

class TaskComponent {
  @NgTwoWay('task')
  Task task;
  Scope _scope;

  TaskComponent([this._scope]) {

  }

  void displayProperties() {
    task.displayProperties(); 
  }
}
```

task_A_component.dart

```
class TaskA extends Task {
  Scope _scope;

  TaskA([this._scope]) {
    Modal.use();
  }

  void displayProperties() {  
    Modal myWindow;
    var readComplete = querySelector('#taskA_Modal');

    myWindow = new Modal(readComplete);
    myWindow.show();   
  }
}

@Component(
    visibility: Directive.CHILDREN_VISIBILITY,
    selector: 'taskA',
    templateUrl: '../lib/components/task_A_component.html',
    publishAs: 'taskACmp',
    useShadowDom: false)

class TaskAComponent {
  @NgTwoWay('taskA')
  TaskA taskA;
  Scope _scopeA;

  TaskAComponent([this._scopeA]) {
    Modal.use();
  }

  void displayProperties() {
    taskA.displayProperties(); 
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-switch which conditionally create the component of your choice

EX:

```
<div ng-switch="ctrl.task.runtimeType">
    <div ng-switch-when="Task">
        <task task="ctrl.task"></task>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="TaskA">
        <taskA taskA="ctrl.task"></taskA>
    </div>
</div>
```

My answer is very late but i hope it can help